# $y'+y-y^2=0$ using Exact differential eq. with integrating factor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? After I use the integrating factor, Fxy still does not seem to be equal to Fyx. I have been staring at my solution for a long time but I can't see my mistake.

Comment: Observe that this is a Bernoulli differential Equation.

Comment: $\int \frac{-1}{y-1}dy=-\ln|y-1|+C$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

Since an integrating factor is, for this case, $$\mu(y)=\exp\left[\int\frac{N_x-M_y}{M}dy\right]$$
we have
$$\int\frac{N_x-M_y}{M}dy=\int\left(\frac{1}{1-y}-\frac{1}{y}\right)=-\ln|1-y|-\ln|y|=\ln\left|\frac{1}{(1-y)y}\right|$$

Then 
$$\mu(y)=\frac{1}{y(1-y)}$$

Multiplying $(y-y^2)dx+dy=0$ by $\mu(y)$ you get the exact differential equation
$$dx+\left(\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{1-y}\right)dy=0$$

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, separation of variables directly produces an exact form
$$
\frac1{y-y^2}dy+1·dx=0
$$